# ¿Cómo representar mediante HTML un trozo de código en Swift u Objective-C?

Tags: javascript, html5, swift, objective-c

¿Cómo puedo representar código Swift u Objective-C en un texto en formato HTML con tabulaciones, colores, ... como se representa en XCode o algún otro editor de código?.

He estado buscando alguna función en javascript pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: ¿Has probado [code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)?

Comment: No conozco esa libreria. Busco algo sencillo simplemente que pueda copiar de otro documento un código con copy + paste  para pasarlo a Html, que se vea con sus tabulaciones, colores...

Comment: Mira entonces mi respuesta y la edición en la que incluyo la biblioteca ACE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pudes hacer uso de la biblioteca de funciones javascript que te proporciona [code prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) para llevar a cabo tu tarea.

Soporta [swift](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-swift.js) a través de una extensión, pero no sé si habrá alguna específica para objective C (imagino que valdrá la genérica para C).

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=css" defer=""></script>
<pre class="prettyprint">
#import &#x3C;Foundation/Foundation.h&#x3E;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@&#x22;Hello, World!&#x22;);
    }
    return 0;
}
</pre>
```

En modo de editor en línea usando la biblioteca de funciones de [ace](https://ace.c9.io):

```css
#editor { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">#import &#x3C;Foundation/Foundation.h&#x3E;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@&#x22;Hello, World!&#x22;);
    }
    return 0;
}</div>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" integrity="sha256-NLPE2EQpOtxTAUB/jxjM97jsGmVQopiX8ceHySHhXs8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/objectivec");
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, estoy buscando una opción que pueda ver html con código swift en offline. Porque la idea es tener anotaciones para consultar.

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres presentar o editar el código? Presentar es sólo mostrarlo sin posibilidad de modificarlo y editar requiere que lo que se ve en la página se pueda modificar.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es un editor de código te he puesto un ejemplo usando ace.

Comment: Si lo quieres offline basta con tener la librería en local, en lugar de apuntar a un CDN

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano por aclarárselo, pero antes de que pueda redactar una respuesta más correcta tendrá que darnos más detalles de a qué se refiere con "ver html con código swift en offline" y a qué se refiere con "la idea es hacer anotaciones para consultar".

Comment: De hecho yo iba a marcar la pregunta como "no está claro lo que se pregunta" hasta que ví que le habías respondido y asumí que quizá no estaba claro sólo para mí :P

Comment: La verdad es que quizá asumí erróneamente un sentido que no era el correcto. Asumo mi culpa @PabloLozano, tienes toda la razón y te apoyo con el voto de cierre. Como hace poco tuve que usar pretty print asumí que era lo que buscaba. Con su comentario asumí que sería ace, pero es cierto que hay bastante ambigüedad en su pregunta.

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder tan rápidamente. Mi idea es hacer un documento en formato html  donde pueda añadir explicaciones en parrafos, alguna imagen y sobre todo código en Swift y Objective-C. El Código debe copiarse de cualquier otra fuente ( documento o pagina web ) al destino con un simple Copy + Paste sin que despues de hacer la copia no tenga que luego retocar caracteres tipo "  por &#x22 u otros parecidos.

Comment: @Popularfan, entonces mira mi última edición, en particular el uso de la biblioteca de funciones ACE. Si quieres usarla "offline" entonces vete a https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js y copia/pega ese javascript en tu HTML. Te permitirá copiar y pegar código de cualquier lenguaje (siempre que selecciones el correcto en `setMode`) y dentro del `<div>` tendrás el código HTML del coloreado para ponerlo donde quieras.

Comment: Ok, perfecto tu información es una gran ayuda. Gracias de nuevo